# Other project types is empty in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

In my system when I click on Add->new project->And go to Other project types I cant see any project types. I actually wanted to convert my c# project to executable.

Is any component missing during installation? I am using Visual studio 2008 professional edition
Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue until I looked into what software I was ACTUALLY using - check to see if you're really using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - I thought I was until I realized I was using Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) which is different.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) is part of the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, so the project types available to it are different than MSVS 2008... Microsoft developed the Shell to have the same look and feel of Visual Studio so users were comfortable and familiar with the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools>>Import and Export Settings>>Reset all settings>>Choose yes or no to save current settings>>

Then choose Visual C# Development Settings or General Development Settings.

So that you can have templates you need.

You can reopen your VisualStudio ISO and try to repair or you can install VisualStudio Express to make sure you can install all templates.

My guess is you didn't make a full installation and forgot to install some components.

Comment: I did this.. But no use.. i still cant see any option in Other project types... i want options similar as shown in this link http://balanagaraj.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/create-exe-or-setup-file-in-net-windows-application/

Comment: Have you tried Reinstalling VS2008 and check to make sure you installed every components ?

Comment: Well i would like to try it..but it will take lot of time..I was thinking if i could know Whats wrong with this.. Re installing will be my last option..

Comment: Well I don't want to argue but I think this is un-usual visual studio behaviour so it means something must have been forgotten while you installed. It's and easy process to install/uninstall. When you out this possibility then you should check for other problems although i'm pretty sure this will work out. Or if you wish you can install vs express 2008 to test.

Comment: Try that and if it doesnt work come back here and we'll try and figure something out